# SortTabs or similar for Sublime Text 3

Tags: sorting, sublimetext3

I would like to have the functionality SortTabs has for Sublime Text 2. But it's not in the default channel anymore in the Package Control list when I search. I also tried to add the repository again via Package Control but to no avail... Do you have any idea then about let it work or replacements for that?
Cheers in advance

Comment: There's https://facelessuser.github.io/TabsExtra/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that downloading the files from the repo and placing them into the `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User` folder (talking about Windows 10) works ;)